# Altering multiple objects in in query

Tags: sql-server, database, alter-table

The code below is attempting to alter 2 columns at once in a table. Can it be done and am I just doing it wrong?

```
Alter table verdata
Add Primary Key(Asset_ID)
Add foreign key(Asdes) References AssetDesc(AssetDescription)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add constraints in alter query,

follow the below,

ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT adds a table-level constraint to an existing table. Any supported table-level constraint type can be added via ALTER TABLE. The following limitations exist on adding a constraint to an existing table:

When adding a foreign key or check constraint to an existing table, Derby checks the table to make sure existing rows satisfy the constraint. If any row is invalid, Derby throws a statement exception and the constraint is not added.

All columns included in a primary key must contain non null data and be unique.

ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY provide a shorthand method of defining a primary key composed of a single column. If PRIMARY KEY is specified in the definition of column C, the effect is the same as if the PRIMARY KEY(C) clause were specified as a separate clause. The column cannot contain null values, so the NOT NULL attribute must also be specified.

For information on the syntax of constraints, see CONSTRAINT clause. Use the syntax for table-level constraint when adding a constraint with the ADD TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT syntax.

[REFERENCE](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html)